# How to get the width of a road through Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to find the width of roads in Google Maps.

Google Earth can't be used as it doesn't support Linux.
Streetviews cannot be used, since it is not available in the area I live.

This link: http://osdir.com/ml/google-maps-js-api-v3/2011-05/msg00666.html suggests the method of finding the distance between the two ends of the road by knowing the coordinates of both sides.

Therefore the first question is as in title.

BTW, I have managed to display the "route" between the two coordinates already on the maps.

The type of the map can be set to "satellite" view through the API.
Does that affect the distance and coordinates that'll be fetched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this stuff about getting points across the street from each other is further complicated by the fact that sometimes the geocode returned will be a ROOFTOP geocode--likely meaning the centroid of a building--and other times, it is RANGE_INTERPOLATED which suggests that it will be not very precise.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderLocationType.  In either case, it won't be the edge of the road.

It may be sobering to look just how far from the road Google Maps may put the marker for an address:  http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=4+Clinton+Drive,+Englishtown,+NJ&aq=&sll=40.299985,-74.290066&sspn=0.009426,0.015213&gl=us&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=4+Clinton+Dr,+Englishtown,+New+Jersey+07726&t=h&z=16

In short, unless your use case can tolerate a pretty wide error bar, I think it's safe to say that this just isn't going to work, at least not without considerable resources at your disposal.

Google Earth web plug-in is not available for Linux, but if you don't need it to be a web page, then you can try working with Google Earth app, perhaps.  It works on Linux.

If your use case is for a reasonably narrow geographical area, there may be data available elsewhere.  But getting this from Google Maps API v3 is unlikely to be a very good option.

(As always when I give a "I don't think this is feasible" answer, I'd be happy for someone to come along and prove me wrong.)

Comment: It occurs to me that if the app is interactive--if you have a user place a marker on each side of the road--you may be able to get sufficient results.  Again, it depends on your use case.

Comment: You have indeed been very helpful Trott, as always. The above post of yours shows very clearly that it is really not feasible. At the same time, the comment of yours talking about the marker placements is indeed very helpful. Thanks again. I try Google Earth today and will post back if I some further questions or new findings.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the coordinates of individual houses. If house numbers are arranged such that n+1 is on another side than n, the distance between the two might tell you something about the width. But I don't think there's an API for that...

Comment: Can you explain more on how to find whether the house numbers are arranged the way you talk of? There is an API for finding the addresses too, I know.

Comment: yea... it's a bit of a hack probably. I'd try to get the coordinates of a few even and a few odd house numbers. Then try to fit a line a) through both lists of coordinates individually, b) through the list of all coordinates. If house numbers are on alternating sides, the points should be much further from the line you obtained from b) than from the individual ones you got in a). A hack, as I said. Will try to think further...

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if we are allowed to plot the markers as said by trott above, if not then ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the NON API solution i thought of,

In my country , roads named with different code names like "A3" , "B354", "C6".
"A" is for main roads. Most of the time width of the road is consistent as per road code. Therefore we can use road code to get the width of the road. I don't know if this works for your country.