# How to get the width of a road

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm developing an Android application that informs the drivers about the condition of the roads. It also informs about the narrow roads that exist on a particular route. So, I need to find the width of the roads. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6251352/7673764) and respective answers, it's not possible to do this using any of the Google Maps APIs.

There is any web mapping service that could do this or any known method that could help to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists the "INSPIRE Directive on Road Infrastructure" in Portugal which you can find more about here:
http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/

In case this isn't quite your fit, there's OpenStreetMap:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width

Comment: Thanks, @Androbin, but I'm developing the application for another country. Wish I could have a dataset to my region as they have for Victoria

Comment: @RicardoFaria Im am sorry, so which country is it exactly?

Comment: Thank you so much for the information @Androbin, I will search more about it

Comment: OpenStreetMap probably has quite some amount of data (for your location) as well.